# Opengl+c++ Need to render a multicolored square but my code is showing blank screen

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl

I am learning Opengl in c++
I am trying to render a multi color square but first I want to show up a simple square.
But all in vain it is showing a blank screen.
I am trying it on xcode
my code is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GLUT/GLUT.h>
#include<OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
void init(void)
{
glShadeModel( GL_SMOOTH ); 
glClearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ); 
glEnable( GL_COLOR_MATERIAL );
glEnable( GL_BLEND );  
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
}
void coloredSquare(void)
{
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glBegin ( GL_LINES );
glColor3f ( 0.9,0.9,0.9 );     // very light gray
for(int i=10;i<180;i+=10)  // vertical lines
{
    glVertex2f( i,0 );
    glVertex2f( i,180 );
}

for(int j=10;j<180;j+=10)   // horizontal lines
{
    glVertex2f( 0,j );
    glVertex2f( 180,j );
}
glEnd();

// b. points
glPointSize(3.0);   // 3 pixel point. why it only works outside of glBegin-glEnd.
glBegin ( GL_POINTS );
glColor3f ( 0.3,0.3,0.3 );     // dark gray
for(int i=10;i<180;i+=10)  // draw point at every grid intersection
{
    for(int j=10;j<180;j+=10)
    {
        glVertex2f( i,j );
    }
}
glEnd();   

glFlush();  // Render now

}   


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
//GLUT & OpenGL
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);

glutInitWindowSize(200, 200);

//glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
glutCreateWindow("GLUT Program");
//glutCreateWindow("Colored Square");
init();
glutDisplayFunc(coloredSquare);
glutMainLoop();
return 0;   /* ISO C requires main to return int. */

}
```

If some body has some idea please do throw some light on this
thanks

Comment: Try calling `glutSwapBuffers()` after `glFlush()` see if that works.

Comment: @anon: He specified `GLUT_SINGLE`, so there should not be a backbuffer to swap with.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Oops. Didn't see that at first.

Answer (score 1):

Your geometry is off. OpenGL's default viewport is (-1..1, -1..1).

Start with something like this at the top of `coloredSquare()`:

```
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(-1, -1, 0);
glScalef(1/90.0, 1/90.0, 1/90.0);
```

Note: Make sure the matrix mode is model-view, which may require prefixing the above lines with the following line if you've set the mode to projection elsewhere:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```